# JavaFX 8 slider is not updating value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My Slider isn't updating when I call the .adjustValue belonging to the Slide class. I also attempted the .setValue only to obtain the same result...
I have the Slider defined in my .fxml and referenced in my controller class below.

I have been stumped for the last two hours...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: REMOVED OLD CODE AND SUBMITTED MORE CONCICSE CODE BELOW:**

Since I wasn't complying with StackOverFlows Minimal Reproducible Example I submited new code below that shows the same issue but more concise.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.File;

public class Controller {

    public Controller(){}

    @FXML
    private Slider songSliderBar;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public void begin(){
        String pathToSong = "PATH TO SONG (IM USING .MP4)";

        Media media = new Media(new File(pathToSong).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

        mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                songSliderBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
                System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldDuration, newDuration) -> {

            double currentValue = newDuration.toSeconds() / mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds();
            songSliderBar.setValue(currentValue);
            System.out.println(currentValue);
        } );

    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: adjustValue definitely is the wrong method for application code - see api doc _This function is intended to be used by experts, primarily by those implementing new Skins or Behaviors._ as to setValue, see my first comment ..

Comment: If the slider’s max is the media’s duration in seconds, the slider’s value should be the media time in seconds, not hundredths of seconds.

Comment: Good catch I changed it. Shouldn't it have changed the progress of the slide bar regardless of the correct computation? The problem that the Slidebar is not updating still remains. I'm in the process of creating a new program from scratch to isolate just the part of code that's causing this issue.

Comment: ahh .. you set max to absolute totalTime, value to proportion of current to total, a very small value compared to max :)

Comment: To clarify, you've set the max value to total-time which means you should set the value to current-time, not current-time / total-time.